# Julia: How to change a package's branch

Tags: git, julia, package-managers

I'm trying to change the branch that I'm using for a package I got from Github. (I don't want to use the master.) I've tried `using Pkg`, then `Pkg.checkout("Package","branchIwant")`, but it comes back as an undefined function.... I'm assuming the function was deprecated. I added the package originally by using `add PackageIWant` in the package manager (pressing `]` when the REPL starts from the terminal). When I navigate to the package under `.julia/packages/PackageIWant`, and I try to change the branch using Git, it says that it isn't a Git repository.

Any suggestions?

Julia v1.3.0.
MacOS - Though that shouldn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [Pkg.jl docs](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/managing-packages/#Adding-packages-1):

> If a branch (or a certain commit) of Example has a hotfix that is not yet included in a registered version, we can explicitly track that branch (or commit) by appending #branchname (or #commitSHA1) to the package name:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Example#master
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaLang/Example.jl.git`
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Project.toml`
  [7876af07] ~ Example v0.5.1 ⇒ v0.5.1+ #master (https://github.com/JuliaLang/Example.jl.git)
  Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.0/Manifest.toml`
  [7876af07] ~ Example v0.5.1 ⇒ v0.5.1+ #master (https://github.com/JuliaLang/Example.jl.git)
```

> The status output now shows that we are tracking the master branch of Example. When updating packages, we will pull updates from that branch.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I found another work around just now, but I think yours is a little more slick.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around:

Instead of adding the package via `add gitrepogttps` use `dev gitrepohttps`. This will put the package in your dev folder (`../.julia/dev/packageinquestion`). Then you can navigate to the branch and use git to switch branches.

Note that this isn't as slick as the answer above.